# Show select option inside a div d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to put a select option inside a div in d3.js, but I could not, this is the code that I am using:

```
var vis = d3.select(".dashboard")
            .select("#sowing")
            .append("div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("id", "chartID")
            .attr("class", "boxing")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 540 250")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 550 / 2 + "," + 300 / 2 + ")");


       var select = vis.append('select')
                .attr("name", "dept-list")
                .attr("class", "form-control");

            var options = select
                .selectAll('option')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('option')
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.text;
                })
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.id;
                });
```

In this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuwnxtn/) show the code to see which is what I want

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is simple: you **cannot** append an HTML element (be it a `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<p>`, `<select>` etc...) to an SVG. It will show up when you inspect the DOM, but nothing will render in the actual SVG.

The best solution here is: don't append HTML elements to the SVG.

But, if (for whatever reason) you really need to create this drop down inside the SVG, you can use [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). It's not a good solution and it will not work on IE. Still, if you want to do it, try this:

```
var foreign = vis.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .append("xhtml:body");

var select = foreign.append('select')
    .attr("name", "dept-list")
    .attr("class", "form-control");
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntxoyhoz/